# undefined method `lessons' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want users to be able to view a task's submit button if and only if they have completed the task's required courses. Right now, I added a line, current_user.complete(@task.courses.all?) to my tasks/show.html.erb page that should only allow a user to view the submit button if they have completed the task's courses. But this line throws an error at the def complete user method saying that the method lessons is undefined for true:TrueClass.

Task Model:

```
has_many :submissions
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

Submission Model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :task
```

Course Model:

```
has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :enrolments
has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks, optional: true
```

Lesson Model:

```
belongs_to :course
has_many :views
has_many :users, through: :views
```

User Model:

```
has_many :courses, through: :enrolments
has_many :submissions
has_many :views
has_many :lessons, through: :views


def view(lesson)
  lessons << lesson
end

def viewed?(lesson)
  lessons.include?(lesson)
end

def complete(course)
  lessons.where(course: course).ids.sort == course.lessons.ids.sort
end
```

Task/Show.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user.complete(@task.courses.all?)%>
  <%= link_to "Submit", new_task_submission_path(@task), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `complete` method expects `course` as a parameter, and it tries to call `course.lessons` on it.

You are calling

```
current_user.complete(@task.courses.all?)
```

which means you are passing a boolean into `complete` instead of a course.

Perhaps you meant something like:

```
@task.courses.all? { |course| current_user.complete(course) }
```

Aleksei Matiushkin suggests that it would be more efficient to use something like:

```
current_user.joins(:courses).joins(:lessons).where(complete: false).count == 0
```

Comment: Please mention that the suggested approach is extremely inefficient and in real life, one should do somewhat like `current_user.joins(:courses).joins.(:lessons)where(complete:  false).count == 0`.